# Decode html tags into a string

Tags: asp.net

I have an attribute in my model which contains html string like below:

```
<p>Solution web de contr&ocirc;le financier &agrave; chacune des &eacute;tapes du cycle de soumission et de validation des d&eacute;penses. La gestion fortement param&eacute;trable des workflows favorise son int& eacute;gration avec des applications tierces (pgm de gestion des d&eacute;penses) et son d& eacute;ploiement dans une organisation d&eacute;centralis&eacute;e.< /p>
```

As you can see we have some html chacacters like `<p> &oirc;` ...

I would like to be able to get this string with all special characters decoded. How can I do?

So this line: **`<p>Solution web de contr&ocirc;le</p>`**

Should give me: **Solution web de contrôle**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`HttpUtility.HtmlDecode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.htmldecode.aspx):

```
string decoded = HttpUtility.HtlmDecode("<p>Solution web de contr&ocirc;le</p>");
```

This will take care of the character entities (`&ocirc;`), but you will still need to strip out the HTML tags.

Answer (score 1):

[`HttpUtility.HTMLDecode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5fyk1k%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) will do what you need.